# Executing INSERT statements with psql, does not load data into Cloud SQL instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, psql

I have a Cloud SQL instance running in my GCP project and I am looking forward to perform the following INSERT statements [1] using 'psql' and my local machine. It looks like that the action is executed without errors, but upon inspecting database from the Cloud Console perspective I am unable to find those inserted rows.

However, if I execute the following command [2] from the psql CLI it returns me the data previously inserted at [1].

In order to throubleshoot this, I logged into my project and reviewed the Log Explorer searching for any errors and I could not find anything related to a permissions issue or similar.

To test this further, I manually added data to the Cloud SQL instance using the console and then fetched this information with the psql CLI [2] and the output only includes the data added with [1].

Questions:

- Am I missing any extra command or parameter with psql to commit data? I used BEGIN; and COMMIT; but the result is the same.
- Why the data inserted from my local machine does not get added to the Cloud SQL instance? The service account that I am using has Admin privileges over the instance.

Relevant information:

- The Cloud SQL instance only has a private IP and I am using locally the Cloud SQL proxy to connect to it. `(I understand that it is not a good practice to keep the proxy locally, but I am testing a few things)`

[1]

```
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (11, 'Alice');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (32, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (13, 'Charlie');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (41, 'David');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (52, 'Eva');
```

[2]
`SELECT * FROM test;`

Comment: Did you commit?

Comment: used the BEGIN; and COMMIT;  before and after the insert statements. The command gets executed, but I do not see any data added to the instance.

Comment: Make sure you're interacting with the same database on the same instance in both cases and that your [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) doesn't redirect you to a different table in a different schema, only sharing the table name. If it was about permissions, you'd get error messages saying so. `SELECT current_database(), current_user; show search_path; select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name='test';`

Comment: It would be very strange for you to randomly end up in a setup like this without knowing, but it would work like this if you were committing changes to the table in one client and ran your checks from another client, from an ongoing transaction with [`repeatable read` isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ). Does anything change if you `commit;` before checking with `select * from test;`? Do you also check with `select * from test;` from the same client that commits the inserts, after insert but before commit, then again after commit?

Comment: Are you the only one with access to this db and instance (that includes both other people as well as external tools that could be using these)? Are there any `triggers` or `rules` in place that could affect your table, or a table it's referencing, where deletes could cascade to this one?

Comment: The instance is new and I am the owner of the project. I reviewed your commands and I observed that the output seems to be correct Schema is public, Database is postgres and table names are correct too. 

I have further tested this with a simple application and I noticed that it retrieves the data that I manually inserted with Cloud Console, not the one with psql. 

I added COMMIT; actions before and after the SELECT command, but still same issue.

Comment: Do you have any other instance running, either up in GCP, locally, or anywhere you have port forwarding set up to, that could be accidentally accepting the connection from your local psql instead of it getting through Cloud SQL proxy to your target Cloud SQL instance? What happens if in client A you do `create table veryuniquetablename1 as select 'hi';` and try to `select * from veryuniquetablename1;` in client B? What happens if you change that name to something different, then create from B and try selecting from it from A?